# Why does my chromium look like this? Is it affected by malware?

Tags: chromium

In the window title of Chromium there is a warning message,

> chromium cannot prevent extensions from recording your browsing history...

Also, in the **Customise and control** options of chromium, there are some warning messages (that aren't being properly displayed). I am not able to open the settings or extensions either.

Why does my Chromium look like this? Is it affected by malware or something else? What can I do to fix it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Disable Chromium extensions, fix your network, fix your Software Updater.

Comment: It might help to start Chromium in incognito mode.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

First close the browser try to remove all config and cache files for chromium:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium
rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium
```

Now open browser and check if all things go well, else try to purge then install:

```
sudo apt-get purge chromium

sudo apt-get install chromium
```

Comment: This is helpful, but doesn't answer the question of _why_ the browser is doing what it's doing.

Comment: @kamil yahoo? !